# UINaviagationBar ignoring background color settings

Tags: ios, objective-c

ios 13, objective-c, can't get the navigation bar background color set.

I've tried setting the color via the UI in interface builder, and several examples off the web (and here).

```
UINavigationBarAppearance* navBarAppearance = [self.navigationController.navigationBar standardAppearance];
navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:172.0f green:193.0f blue:197.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

I would expect the above code to set the background color, but it's still white.

Comment: You do know that those color numbers are totally bogus, right?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:172.0f green:193.0f blue:197.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

to this:

```
navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:172.0f/255.0f green:193.0f/255.0f  blue:197.0f/255.0f  alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd forgotten about that bit. Thanks, works!